# JFrame content displayed with a delay

Tags: java, jframe, loading

I have an applet with a main view and multiple additional pop-up JFrames.
One JFrame (Report() ) takes more than 20 seconds to load because of an SQL query.
I would like to display a pop-up JFrame which would warn the user, that the requested window is loading, but the content of the pop-up JFrame is displayed only after the asked JFrame was loaded.

This is the code that I have:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loading");

JLabel label = new JLabel("My label");
label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 16));
label.setText("<html> Please wait while </br> report loads </br>");
JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.add(label);
top.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

frame.add(top);
frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);

new Report();
```

In Report I do not have a main() method, I initialize it from the constructor directly with:

```
    // setting up the cross-platform look and feel
    preInitComponents();
    // setting up the UI
    initComponents();
    // visualizing the jframe
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use JOptionPane? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: USing swingutilities.invokelater should fix the problem btw.

Comment: I would like to customize it maybe further later. Probably a progress bar would be the ideal solution, but that still would be placed on a JFrame

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information about the problem you're trying to solve and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible way to solve it

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113644/java-global-reusable-loading-dialog/14114663#14114663) ... although you probably don't need the progress bar ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, will try to understand and implement your solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks, your example did the trick...